# Webview not displaying Twitter on some Droids

Tags: android, twitter

This is an obscure, possibly hardware dependent error.

I have a webview that is trying to display a twitter feed like this: http://twitter.com/HP

The view works fine on a Droid 2, but fails on Droid and Droid X.

Instead of displaying the page, it just displays the twitter logo and hangs forever.

about the devices:

All running the same software, and Android 2.2. However, they are running different flavors of Android 2.2.
Droid X: 2.2.1
Droid 1: 2.2.2
Droid 2: 2.2

It seems that Verizon must have added a bug or fixed a bug in their later versions of 2.2.

Comment: Hardware dependent webview? Sounds strange. Can you verify if the page data is actually transmitted in full in all cases? Also, are there differences between HTTP headers sent by the devices?

Comment: Are they all running the same software ?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This is the answer:

add this:

```
        webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

(plus use code from here:
http://www.codelark.com/2010/09/13/backwards-compatibility-in-android-using-reflection/)

I have no idea why, but if you ever see an error message like this:
Web Console: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'profile' of undefined 
then try adding this setting.

Comment: The given link (codelark) doesn't work anymore. Could you please provide the code given over there ?

Comment: This is exactly what I needed to do!

Comment: This is a God send! My app was suffering with this for months! Thanks you!