# android mobile twitter page in webview not opening?

Tags: android, android-webview

I am trying to open twitter page begining with https in `webview` in android. But it is not opening and blank screen is coming with continous loading. Screen shot is below

[image]

**Edit:** In main webview I have link to twitter page `https://twitter.com/mytwitterpage`. On clicking that link that twitter url is opening in webview. I noticed that onPageFinished method of WebViewClient is called 2 times one time for `https://twitter.com/mytwitterpage` and second time for `https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/mytwitterpage`.

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: May be internet speed cause this problem.

Comment: I dont think internet speed is issue here as I have searched internet and many people has faced this problem.

Comment: Have you enabled JavaScript for the webview by calling [`WebView.setJavaScriptEnabled(true)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled(boolean))? It's disabled by default and it looks like this site depends on js to me.

Comment: @alextsc yes i have written this webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Ok done by adding below line in my code

```
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U; Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
```

I got it from this post at stackoverflow [Problems loading mobile.twitter in webview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856814/problems-loading-mobile-twitter-in-webview).

Answer (score 3):

```
wv.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

This worked for me!

Comment: Works perfectly and doesn't change the rendering of the page (which is not the case with the anujprashar's answer)

Answer (score 0):

Are you hitting a https:// page? If so, try setting a WebViewClient on your webview and override onReceivedSslError and see if there something wrong.

Twitter changed some certificate stuff recently, if you're hitting twitter.com/... try hitting api.twitter.com/...

Comment: I override that method and I see no error and also I am opening twitter page by clicking on link and not by directly supplying url. I have edited question, please check it.

Comment: Can open the URL in the devices browser?

Comment: Yes, It opened in browser of phone. I typed https://twitter.com/mytwitterpage in address bar and initially black screen like above screen shot appeared for 3-4 seconds and after url changed to https://mobile.twitter.com/#!/mytwitterpage and page opened in browser.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, this was my case, I was getting "primary error: 3". This is on Android 1.6 only, later versions work fine. Any idea why this is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Just add this code below webview. It solved my problem.

```
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.addJavascriptInterface(this, "TwitterDownloader");
```