# Android WebView not rendering webpage correctly

Tags: android, webview

I have a strange problem with my webview.  I have a basic webview that I use to display webpages.  This works the majority of the time, but there is one site in particular that does not render.  I am not sure how to begin to debug this problem.  Here is my initialization code for the webview:

```
    webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.rss_webView);
    webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url)
        {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    });

    webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
        public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress)
        {

            pb.setProgress(progress);


            if (progress == 100)
                pb.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            else
                pb.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }


    });

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(true);

    webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

The URL that is having problems is:   http://twitter.com/AdamSchefter/statuses/236553635608285184

This page (and other twitter pages) render as a blank gray square on the screen with no content.

I have noticed that if I open the url with my normal Android browser it gets redirected to a mobile version.  The webview does not do this as far as I can tell.  When setting breakpoints in the shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method, I don't receive any redirect urls.

I have scanned logcat for any indication of error.  I don't think the webview performs any logging to log cat at all (other than a not that a webview was loaded) because there is nothing there.

I am not sure how to track down this issue.  Any thoughts?

I have a lot of twitter sources that I need to display and I don't have control over the URL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Ok done by adding below line in my code
>
> ```
> webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; U;`
> Android 2.0; en-us; Droid Build/ESD20) AppleWebKit/530.17 (KHTML, like
> Gecko) Version/4.0 Mobile Safari/530.17");
> ```
>
> I got it from this post at stackoverflow Problems loading mobile.twitter in webview.

[android mobile twitter page in webview not opening?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8056063/android-mobile-twitter-page-in-webview-not-opening)

Also, if it's not redirecting you to the mobile version of twitter, you can just append mobile to it, i.e. mobile.twitter.com

Comment: Well don't I feel sheepish.  I searched through countless webview posts but for some reason didn't think to actually search for a solution involving Twitter.  I guess I should have since it is popular enough and someone was bound to have had the same problem.  Thanks for the help!