# Android webview doesn't open twitter page properly

Tags: android, webview, chromium

I have an Android app which opens some pages in webview. You can see the

[screenshot of the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM9CD.png). I can't see the tweets on can see the header.

I have tried all webview settings but it is not working properly.

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
webview.setWebChromeClient(new MyWebChromeClient);
webview.getSettings().setDefaultTextEncodingName("utf-8");
webview.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.getSettings().setDisplayZoomControls(false);
webview.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
webview.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webview.getSettings().setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
webview.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
```

[edit]
I am getting error on console below :

```
I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Refused to load the image 'https://www.google.com.tr/ads/ga-audiences?v=1&aip=1&t=sr&_r=4&tid=UA-30775-67&cid=1855674525.1467776671&jid=2048800659&_v=j44&z=267031279&ipr=y' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "img-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' blob: data: https://*.cdn.twitter.com https://ton.twitter.com https://*.twimg.com https://stats.g.doubleclick.net https://www.google.com https://www.google-analytics.com https://www.periscope.tv".
            ", source: https://mobile.twitter.com/home (0)
```

Comment: Post the complete logs.

Comment: check this link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856814/problems-loading-mobile-twitter-in-webview

Comment: Yes. I have already checked prakask. But i have checked the log. There is no clear problem. You can check the problem in my app from https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tr.com.socialmedia address. This is new it working just twp weeks ago. But i dont what has changed it is not working for after webview 4.4.

Comment: I am getting error on console below:

Comment: Did anyone find a solution?  I too am having the same problem.  Once logged into Twitter while inside the webview, tweets don't show.  Scrolling down, then up slowly and some will show for a second then disappear.   If I log out, the tweets show up fine.  html5test.com shows the webview is "Chromium WebView 43" on my Samsung S7.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must set layout_width and layout_height attributes like below.

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
```